# "Resize" arbitrary coordinates (inches) to EPSG46

Tags: coordinates, ogr2ogr, scale, dxf

I'm using ogr2ogr to transform an AutoCAD (DXF) file to GeoJSON. The GeoJSON file is generated, but with very large coordinates, for example `"coordinates": [ [ [ 6319.645968701713173, 9523.353045375093643, 0.0 ]`.

This probably comes from the fact that the DXF file has no notion of coordinates, only dimensions (very large ones). I would like to "transform" those arbitrary coordinates to standard `EPSG:4326` coordinates, by scaling them down. I have no preference on where it will get displayed on the final map, but I need this coordinates to fit in a fixed bounds.

I did not find any ogr2ogr method to "scale down" coordinates, any idea on how I could do this?

Comment: Most GIS packages are better at real-world conversons than arbitrary ones. Scaling arbitrary Cartesian coordinates into degrees is particularly error-prone.

Comment: @Vince I know about that, but let's say we fix an "origin" point, if we just compute the position, based on a transformation method from my arbitrary coordinates to a metric system, with the origin it should be doable ? Maybe no such tool exist, but with a combination of existing tools (I've used turf in the past, which offer the ability to add point at specific length)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only do you have to convert, you also have to transform.
You take a (any) metric system and transform according to EPSG: 4326.

```
ogr2ogr -skipfailures  --config DXF_MERGE_BLOCK_GEOMETRIES FALSE  ^
    --config DXF_ENCODING "CP1252" -sql "select *, ogr_style from entities"  -nln "entities"  -f "GeoJSON"  ^
    -s_srs "EPSG:27398"  ^
    -t_srs "EPSG:4326" ^
    "target.GeoJSON" "source.dxf"
```